# PHP website search and display items

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a dummy online store to illustrate some real world functionality which one of them is to search the website for items i.e.

I have written PHP code to deal with this scenario but it does not work properly. Wchat it does dough is it matches the results and the number of results but it does not display them which I of course wont it to do.

Been trying to look for answers on GOOGLE but didn't find corresponding solution or a tip to my problem.

Here am gonna list the code I am using:

PHP code (search.php):

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    include('connect_mysql.php');

    $product_name = 'product_name';
    $product_qua = 'product_qua';
    $product_price = 'product_price';
    $product_image = 'product_image';
    $product_des = 'product_des';


    if (isset($_POST['keyword'])) 
    {
        $search = $_POST['keyword'];

        if (!empty($search))
        {
            $query = "SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE product_name='$search'";
            $query_search = mysql_query($query);

            echo mysql_num_rows($query_search);

            if (mysql_num_rows($query_search) >=1)
            {
                echo 'Results found: <br>';

                while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_row($query_search)) 
                {
                    echo $query_row['product_name'];

                }
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query_search))
                { ?>
                    <table id='display'>
                    <tr><td><?php echo "<img src=$rows[$product_image] class='grow'>" ?></td></tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><strong>Avalible</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td width='290px'><?php echo "$rows[$product_name]" ?></td>
                    <td width='290px'><?php echo "$rows[$product_qua]" ?></td>
                    <td width='290px'><?php echo "£ $rows[$product_price]" ?></td>
                    <td width='290px'><?php echo "$rows[$product_des]" ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><p>Please Login To purchase this item </p><br /><a href="login.php">Login</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                <?php
                }

            } else {
              echo 'NO results found.';

            }

        }
    }

?>
```

HTML code (index.php):

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="keyword" size="20" placeholder="Search for products...."/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search >>" />

</form>
```

Print screen of current result:

[image]

As you have have noticed it also says 3 results have been found which is correct considering i have searched for ever which is a common name of my product but drows up only two tables moreover they are empty.

website url: http://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/~k1024026/index.php

finally my product table consists of : product_id   product_name    product_qua product_price   product_image   product_des product_type attrebiutes/columns

anyone can spot where i might be going wrong with this....?

Answer (score 0):

First, try removing this

```
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_row($query_search)) 
                {
                    echo $query_row['product_name'];

                }
```

I also noticed a few bad typo in your code :

- table id="display" an id should be unique. If you iterate over it and still want it to be an id, put display-n instead, n being the unique id of the product for example. (or use class="display" instead of id)
- You should take a look at sql injection and how to defeat them.

Answer (score 0):

I might rather do this:

```
$query = "SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE %" . $search . "%";
```

Hope it will help.  Then use a foreach loop to run through the result like:

```
foreach ($search as $key => $result){
      echo $result . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `mysql_fetch_row( $query_search)` returns a plain array not an associative array but you are trying to access its values using keys - `$query_row [ 'product_name' ]`. Rather use `_fetch_array`
2. There are lots of syntactical errors. There is a space between function name and list of parameters.
3. Don't use `mysql_`. They are deprecated (read: dead). Use PDO instead.

Comment: Ok thx for your reply but how would I implement the changes you suggested.

Comment: and why does mysql_fetch_row( $query_search) returns a plain array...?

Comment: @Tomazi What do you mean - '_why does mysql_fetch_row( $query_search) returns a plain array_'? It is because the developers have decided it that way. Read PHP manual on PDO.