# PHP MySQL Shopping Cart - Adding items to session

Tags: php, mysql

I am practicing with PHP, and as a result, I ended up creating a dummy online store. I managed to implement most of the online functionality, but I am struggling with the shopping cart.

Once the user logs in and enters the product area of the site, I want the user to be able to add items to a cart. I have been following a [phpAcademy YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bbw-z9HyN-s). I've managed to display all the products with an add button/hyperlink to link each product to a processing page called cart.php. Each button's link matches their associated product ID.

When I test this and click "add", the ID of the product does not appear on the cart.php page.

user_man_boxing_gloves.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('connect_mysql.php');

$product_name = 'product_name';
$product_qua = 'product_qua';
$product_price = 'product_price';
$product_image = 'product_image';
$product_des = 'product_des';

$get = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, product_image, product_name, product_des, product_price, product_type FROM products WHERE product_type='ManGloves' AND product_qua > 0 ORDER BY product_id DESC");
if(mysql_num_rows($get) == 0)
{
    echo "There are no Products to display";
}
else
{
    ?>
    <?php
    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
    {
        ?>
        <table id='display'>
            <tr><td><?php echo "<img src=$get_row[$product_image] class='grow'>" ?></td></tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><strong>Avalible</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_name]" ?></td>
                <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_qua]" ?></td>
                <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_price]" ?></td>
                <td width='290px'><?php echo "$get_row[$product_des]" ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo '<a href="cart.php?add=' . $get_row['product_id'] . '">Add</a>'; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

cart.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';

}

echo $_SESSION['cart_'];

?>
```

I want to display the product ID to see if my code works, and I want to do further processing after verifying that it works.

[image]

Looking at the screenshot, it appears that the add button correctly shows the product ID.

Comment: Maybe **shopping** cart?)

Comment: How is this different then your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351854/php-website-search-and-display-items)?

Comment: How.....? if you read it then you might spot the difference, dont understand why people are down voting a genuine question......

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk: It appears that this question asks about adding items to the shopping cart, while the other question asks about listing items.

Comment: @Tomazi: I think part of it is from spelling/grammar in the question. In any case, it doesn't look like `$page` is being used in cart.php. Is this intentional?

Comment: and sorry if my english is bad or unclear in some parts but as english is not my first language i guess i can only write best i can, as long as the question is understandable.....So for these that do understand it and are willing to point out my mistakes in my code or suggest a solution.....I appreciate it a lot, As it will help my learning process. Regards

Comment: @ChrisForrence unintentional......OK so now i understand that it is correct to down vote for spelling and grammar......? if this is the case this site gives little chance that a foreign person can get a answer and the Site Owners should place a notice that this is only for people that can write 100% english

Comment: @Tomazi: It's not correct or a good reason, but it is definitely a reason that people use to at least pass up a question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue in cart.php deals with the following snippet:

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
        $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
}
```

Working this out, this would mean that with an ID of 1, you could see the following in your session array:

> $_SESSION['cart_1'] = 1;
>   $_SESSION['cart_2'] = 4;

What you probably want, for the display, is to store an array into cart. That is,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $arr = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else
{
    $arr = array();
}

if(isset($_GET['add'])){
        $arr[$_GET['add']] += 1;
}
$_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($arr);

var_dump(unserialize($_SESSION['cart']));
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay much appreciated...I will get bk to my coding amend the changes and see the result i will let you know. once again thx

Comment: Ok so i have tried your suggestion and the following result was echoed out in cart.php: bool(false)

Comment: @Tomazi: Updated the answer to check if the session variable is set before attempting to unserialize it

Comment: @Tomazi : Did this revision help?

Comment: ok i fixed it basically............. i changed the session structure from what i had to $_SESSION['cart'] = $_GET['add']++;, Now the session == clicked add button id just what i wanted. Thanks for trying helping me..really appreciated it.....Most people don't want to  help i guess they are professorial that know everything and never seen someone that struggles in a given area which obviously defeats  the purpose of the existence of this site :)